# Updating data in an Oracle table on a daily basis

Tags: database, oracle, dbeaver

I use dbeaver to work with the Oracle database and the task is how to update the data in the table daily (I created a new table using a complex sql query)?

I created a task, but in dbeaver, as far as I know, the task scheduler is only in the Enterprise and Ultimate editions. Tell me how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

DBeaver is just a tool; use databases scheduling capabilities, i.e.

- update should be part of a **stored procedure**
- schedule it with `dbms_scheduler`

For example, if procedure's name is `p_update`, you'd e.g. schedule it to run from Monday to Friday at 23:00 as

```
BEGIN
   DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB (
      job_name         => 'p_update',
      job_type         => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
      job_action       => 'BEGIN p_update; END;',
      start_date       =>
         TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ ('27.06.2023 23:00 Europe/Zagreb',
                          'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi TZR'),
      repeat_interval  =>
         'FREQ=DAILY; BYDAY=MON,TUE,WED,THU,FRI; BYHOUR=23; BYMINUTE=0',
      enabled          => TRUE,
      comments         => 'Updating my table');
END;
/
```